# Tabs in actionbar and tabbar with backbutton

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm developing an android application, and I want 2 tabs in the actionbar, and 6 tabs in a tabbar below the action bar.

Furthermore, a fragment in the actionbar should be stackable. So I've got a number of tabs, for instance a, b, c, and d.

tab a and b should be able to transition,

a -> a1 -> a2

b -> b1

When a user presses the back button when on b1, it should go to b. If the user presses the back button on b, nothing should happen.
If a user is on tab b, section b1, and goes to tab a, and then back to tab b, it's not necessary to return to b1.

So, my two questions are:

Is there a way to display tabs on, and below the actionbar?

I know this is bad design, but my client insist on it.

Is there a way to use the back button when navigating within a tab?